# Replace text in already opened text file using QTP/VB scripting

Tags: vbscript, qtp, filesystemobject

Can anyone tell me please .How to replace text in a notepad file which is already opened and i don't know the path of this file.

Thanks
Dev

Comment: I doubt that this is possible with VBScript.

Comment: Any other way of doing this like ShelScript etc  which i can implement in QTP script/VBS file

Answer (score 0):

QTP supports notepad, just use the built in methods:

```
Window("Noteapad").WinEditor("Edit").Type "Hello world"
```

If you want to replace text, first select the text you want replaced (for example, replace all the text up to the cursor, like this):

```
line = Window("Notepad").WinEditor("Edit").GetROProperty("line")
column = Window("Notepad").WinEditor("Edit").GetROProperty("colmun")
Window("Notepad").WinEditor("Edit").SetSelection 0, 0, line, column 
Window("Notepad").WinEditor("Edit").Type "Hello World
```

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey if your cursor is at the beginning of the file then that's its position (line and column show current location of cursor)